# How can i get multiple affiliate accounts to display in one place?

Tags: statistics, tracking, text-mining, affiliate

I would like to know how i can extract stats and content updates from various webmaster affiliation programs to display in a single app and or website . I would need the following info , sales and conversions, click stats , webmaster referrals , website affiliate links, content updates ,and payout schedules.

keeping in mind that these affiliates have different logins.

Answer (score 0):

There are besically two ways of doing this:

1. Use the affiliate program's API's.
2. Build scrapers for each website. The scraper will basically log on to each site and extract all the info needed on a given interval.

No-1 is preferred but not all affiliate programs have API's. Take a look at current services like this and see a bit how they work. Take a look at StatsRemote. They are storing all the usernames and passwords locally on every users computer.